# How long does an Async SOQL query against big objects take?

Tags: big-object

Is there a ballpark for how long async SOQL queries on big objects take?  I know i depends on the size of the data, but are we talking minutes vs hours vs days?

Comment: whats the amount of data you are referring to? (i personally am clueless)

Comment: Potentially upto 40 million rows

Answer (score 0):

40 million rows is a relatively small data set for big objects, so should execute relatively quickly.

A presentation by Salesforce had a dataset with 1 Billion order line items, it was suggested that an aggregate query on that dataset would take around 10 minutes.

So I expect your query would run more quickly than that.

You can watch the presentation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TffHL8HplQM